# The beautiful pattern drawer (Little cubes included)

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, grid, base-conversion

## The beautiful pattern drawer

Good morning PPCG !

The other day, when I was trying to help someone on Stack Overflow, a part of his problem gave me an idea for this challenge.

First of all, check the following shape :

[image]

Where all black numbers are the index of the points in the shape and all dark-blue numbers are the index of the links between the points.

Now, given an hexadecimal number for 0x00000 to 0xFFFFF, you need to draw a shape in the console using only character space and "■" (using the character "o" is okay too).

Here are some examples where hexadecimal number is input and shape is output :

```
0xE0C25 :
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■               ■ 
■               ■ 
■               ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
        ■       ■ 
        ■       ■ 
        ■       ■ 
        ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
0xC1043 :
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
              ■   
            ■     
          ■       
        ■         
      ■           
    ■             
  ■               
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
0xE4F27 :
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
0xF1957 :
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■ ■           ■ ■ 
■   ■       ■   ■ 
■     ■   ■     ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■     ■   ■     ■ 
■   ■       ■   ■ 
■ ■           ■ ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
0xD0C67 :
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
  ■             ■ 
    ■           ■ 
      ■         ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
      ■ ■       ■ 
    ■   ■       ■ 
  ■     ■       ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
0x95E30 :
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
  ■     ■     ■ ■ 
    ■   ■   ■   ■ 
      ■ ■ ■     ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
        ■ ■       
        ■   ■     
        ■     ■   
        ■       ■ 
0x95622 :
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
  ■     ■     ■   
    ■   ■   ■     
      ■ ■ ■       
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
        ■         
        ■         
        ■         
■ ■ ■ ■ ■         
0xC5463 : 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
        ■     ■   
        ■   ■     
        ■ ■       
■ ■ ■ ■ ■         
      ■ ■         
    ■   ■         
  ■     ■         
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
0xE5975 :
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■       ■     ■ ■ 
■       ■   ■   ■ 
■       ■ ■     ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■     ■ ■ ■     ■ 
■   ■   ■   ■   ■ 
■ ■     ■     ■ ■ 
■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
0xB5E75 :
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
■ ■     ■     ■ ■ 
■   ■   ■   ■   ■ 
■     ■ ■ ■     ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
      ■ ■ ■     ■ 
    ■   ■   ■   ■ 
  ■     ■     ■ ■ 
■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
0xF4C75 :
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■ ■     ■       ■ 
■   ■   ■       ■ 
■     ■ ■       ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
      ■ ■ ■     ■ 
    ■   ■   ■   ■ 
  ■     ■     ■ ■ 
■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
0xF5D75 :
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■ ■     ■     ■ ■ 
■   ■   ■   ■   ■ 
■     ■ ■ ■     ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
■     ■ ■ ■     ■ 
■   ■   ■   ■   ■ 
■ ■     ■     ■ ■ 
■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
```

Here are some explanation about how it works :

```
0xFFFFF(16) = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111(2)
```

You here have 20 bits, each bit says whether a link exists or not.

Index of the Most Significant Bit (MSB) is 0 (picture reference) or the Less Significant Bit (LSB) is 19 (picture reference again).

Here's how it works for the first shape given as example :

```
0xE0C25(16) = 1110 0000 1100 0010 0101(2)
```

Meaning you'll have the following existing links : 0,1,2,8,9,14,17,19.

If you highlight the lines on the reference picture with those numbers, it will give you this shape :

```
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■               ■ 
■               ■ 
■               ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
        ■       ■ 
        ■       ■ 
        ■       ■ 
        ■ ■ ■ ■ ■
```

Here is a simple and ungolfed Python implementation if you need more help :

```
patterns = [
  0xE0C25, 0xC1043, 0xE4F27, 0xF1957, 
  0xD0C67, 0x95E30, 0x95622, 0xC5463, 
  0xE5975, 0xB5E75, 0xF4C75, 0xF5D75
]

def printIfTrue(condition, text = "■ "):
  if condition:
    print(text, end="")
  else:
    print(" "*len(text), end="")

def orOnList(cube, indexes):
  return (sum([cube[i] for i in indexes]) > 0)

def printPattern(pattern):
  cube = [True if n == "1" else False for n in str(bin(pattern))[2::]]
  for y in range(9):
    if y == 0: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [0, 2, 3]))
    if y == 4: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [2, 4, 9, 11, 12]))
    if y == 8: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [11, 13, 18]))
    if y in [0, 4, 8]:
      printIfTrue(cube[int((y / 4) + (y * 2))], "■ ■ ■ ")
      if y == 0: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [0, 1, 4, 5, 6]))
      if y == 4: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15]))
      if y == 8: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [12, 14, 16, 18, 19]))
      printIfTrue(cube[int((y / 4) + (y * 2)) + 1], "■ ■ ■ ")
    elif y in [1, 5]:
      for i in range(7):
        if i in [2, 5]:
          print(" ", end=" ")
        printIfTrue(cube[y * 2 + (1 - (y % 5)) + i])
    elif y in [2, 6]:
      for i in range(5):
        if i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
          print(" ", end=" ")
        if i in [1, 3]:
          if i == 1 and y == 2:
            printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [3, 4]))
          elif i == 3 and y == 2:
            printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [6, 7]))
          if i == 1 and y == 6:
            printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [12, 13]))
          elif i == 3 and y == 6:
            printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [15, 16]))
        else:
          printIfTrue(cube[(y * 2 - (1 if y == 6 else 2)) + i + int(i / 4 * 2)])
    elif y in [3, 7]:
      for i in range(7):
        if i in [2, 5]:
          print("  ", end="")
        ri, swap = (y * 2 - 2) + (1 - (y % 5)) + i, [[3, 6, 12, 15], [4, 7, 13, 16]]
        if ri in swap[0]: ri = swap[1][swap[0].index(ri)]
        elif ri in swap[1]: ri = swap[0][swap[1].index(ri)]
        printIfTrue(cube[ri])
    if y == 0: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [1, 7, 8]))
    if y == 4: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [6, 8, 10, 16, 17]))
    if y == 8: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [15, 17, 19]))
    print()

for pattern in patterns:
  printPattern(pattern)
```

Of course it's not perfect and it's pretty long for what it should do, and that's the exact reason why you're here !

Making this program ridiculously short :)

This is code-golf, so shortest answer wins !

Comment: Can we print a single trailing space on lines? Your examples contain them.

Comment: Yup :) It's allowed

Comment: Is graphical output allowed?

Comment: Is a leading space allowed as well?

Comment: Does it have to be a function, or can we get input directly from the user?

Comment: Do you require hexadecimal input or is decimal ok?

Comment: Maybe all the code golf is just getting to me, but that code is painful to read…

Comment: @12Me21 You can get input from user !

Comment: @12Me21 Graphical output is not allowed as you can use some stuff like "drawline" and not have to care abour corners overlapping :)

Comment: @Arnauld Leading space is allowed, doesn't change much here :)

Comment: @Titus Hexadecimal required !

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>202</s> <s>188</s> 187 bytes

```js
let f =

n=>`0${x=',16,-54,21,-26,21,21,-26,21,166'}${x},16`.split`,`.map((d,i)=>(k-=d,n)>>i&1&&[..."ooooo"].map(c=>g[p-=(k&3||9)^8]=c,p=k>>2),g=[...(' '.repeat(9)+`
`).repeat(9)],k=356)&&g.join``

console.log(f(0xE0C25))
console.log(f(0xC1043))
console.log(f(0xE4F27))
console.log(f(0xF1957))
```

#### How it works

```js
n =>                                                 // given 'n':
  `0${x = ',16,-54,21,-26,21,21,-26,21,166'}${x},16` // build the list of delta values
  .split`,`.map((d, i) =>                            // split the list and iterate
    (k -= d, n) >> i & 1 &&                          // update 'k', test the i-th bit of 'n'
    [..."ooooo"].map(c =>                            // if the bit is set, iterate 5 times:
      g[                                             // 
        p -= (k & 3 || 9) ^ 8                        // compute the direction and update 'p'
      ] = c,                                         // write a 'o' at this position
      p = k >> 2                                     // initial value of 'p'
    ),                                               //
    g = [...(' '.repeat(9) + `\n`).repeat(9)],       // initialization of the 'g' array
    k = 356                                          // initial value of 'k'
  )                                                  //
  && g.join``                                        // yield the final string
```

We work on a grid `g` of 9 rows of 10 characters. The grid is initially filled with spaces, with a LineFeed every 10th character.

Each segment is defined by a starting position and a direction.

Directions are encoded as follow:

```
ID | Dir.| Offset
---|-----|-------
 0 |  W  |  -1        Offset encoding formula:
 1 | NE  |  -9        -((ID || 9) ^ 8)
 2 |  N  |  -10
 3 | NW  |  -11
```

Each segment is encoded as an integer:

- the direction is stored in bits #0 and #1
- the starting position is stored in bits #2 to #8

For instance, segment #3 starts at position 55 and uses the 3rd direction. Therefore, it's encoded as `(55 << 2) | 3 == 223`.

Below is the resulting list of integers, from segment #19 to segment #0:

```
356,340,394,373,399,378,357,383,362,196,180,234,213,239,218,197,223,202,36,20
```

Once delta-encoded, starting at 356, it becomes:

```
0,16,-54,21,-26,21,21,-26,21,166,16,-54,21,-26,21,21,-26,21,166,16
```

Which is finally encoded as:

```
`0${x=',16,-54,21,-26,21,21,-26,21,166'}${x},16`
```

Comment: Oops... Forgot the spaces in between. Fixing that.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, 289 bytes

```py
def f(n):
 for r in range(9):print(*(" o"[any(n&1<<ord(c)-97for c in"trq|t|t|t|tspon|s|s|s|sml|r|q||p|o|n||m|l|r||qp||o||nm||l|r|p||q|o|m||n|l|rpkih|k|k|k|qomkjgfe|j|j|j|nljdc|i|h||g|f|e||d|c|i||hg||f||ed||c|i|g||h|f|d||e|c|igb|b|b|b|hfdba|a|a|a|eca".split("|")[r*9+c])]for c in range(9)))
```

Nothing smart, just hardcoding.

Comment: Couldn't `"trq|t...a|eca".split("|")` become `"tqr t...a eca".split()`?

Comment: @Loovjo Nope, `.split()` destroys `||`.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 116 bytes

```
->n{s=[' '*17]*9*$/
20.times{|i|j=i%9
n>>19-i&1>0&&5.times{|k|s[i/9*72+(j>1?~-j/3*8+k*18:j*16)+k*(2--j%3*2)]=?O}}
s}
```

This relies on a couple of patterns I observed. Firstly, the pattern repeats every 9 lines. Secondly, if the start points of the horizontal lines are chosen appropriately, the x directions cycle continuously through right, left, straight.

**Ungolfed in test program**

```
f=->n{
   s=[' '*17]*9*$/                    #Setup a string of 9 newline separated lines of 17 spaces.
   20.times{|i|                       #For each of the 20 bits..
     j=i%9                            #The pattern repeats every 9 bits.
     n>>19-i&1>0&&                    #If the relevant bit is set,
     5.times{|k|                      #draw each of the 5 points on the relevant line.
       s[i/9*72+                      #There are 9 lines starting on each row. Row y=0 starts at 0 in the string, row y=1 at 72, etc.
       (j>1?~-j/3*8+k*18:j*16)+       #~-j=j-1. For j=2..8, the starting x coordinates are (0,0,1,1,1,2,2)*8. For j=0 and 1 starting x coordinates are 0 and 16. 
       k*(2--j%3*2)                   #From the starting points, draw the lines right,left,straight. Down movement if applicable is given by conditional k*18 above.
       ]=?O                           #Having described the correct index to modify, overwrite it with a O character.
     }
   }
s}                                    #Return the string.


[0xE0C25, 0xC1043, 0xE4F27, 0xF1957, 
  0xD0C67, 0x95E30, 0x95622, 0xC5463, 
  0xE5975, 0xB5E75, 0xF4C75, 0xF5D75].map{|m|puts f[m],'---------'}
```

I believe there is a 112 byte solution using a 20-character string and some decoding to define the parameters of the 20 lines. I will try this later if I have time.

Comment: Nice explanation !

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>142</s> <s>150</s> 149 bytes

```php
for($r="";$c=ord(",(NMKJIGFHDjigfecbd`"[$i]);)if(hexdec($argv[1])>>$i++&1)for($p=96^$c&~$k=3;$k++<8;$p+=7+($c&3?:-6))$r[$p]=o;echo chunk_split($r,9);
```

prints the shape as far as needed; i.e. if the lower part is empty, it will be cut.
Run with `php -nr '<code>' <input>`. Do not prefix input

**[Test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c6c3f16b2d9c2705813df012c79a213f331fd6c9)**

Add 11 bytes for no cutting: Insert `,$r[80]=" "` after `$r=""`.

**encoding explained**

Every line can be described with a starting point and one of four directions.
Drawing on a 9x9 grid, the starting position ranges from `0,0` to `8,4`; or, combined, from `0` to `8*9+4=76`. Luckily, all starting points `[0,4,8,36,40,44,72,76]` are divisible by 4; so the direction code `[0..3]` can be squeezed into bits 0 and 1 -> no shifting needed at all.

For an easy calculation of the cursor movement, `0` is taken for east (only direction with no vertical movement) and `[1,2,3]` for south-west, south, south-east, where the offset is `9` (for vertical movement) plus `[-1,0,1]` -> `[8,9,10]` -> `delta=code?code+7:1`.

The direction for the first and last lines being east, that results in codes ranging from 0 to 76 `[0+0,4+0,0+2,0+3,4+1,4+2,4+3,8+1,8+2,...,44+1,44+2,72+0,76+0]`; and bitwise xor 96 on each value results in printable and unproblematic ascii codes `[96,100,98,99,101,102,103,105,106,68, 72,70,71,73,74,75,77,78,40,44]` ->  `` `dbcefgijDHFGIJKMN(, ``. The code uses the LSB for bit 0, while line 0 corresponds to the MSB, so the string has to be reversed. Finito.

**breakdown**

```php
for($r="";                  // init result string, loop through line codes
    $c=ord(",(NMKJIGFHDjigfecbd`"[$i]);)
    if(hexdec($argv[1])>>$i++&1)// if bit $i is set, draw line 19-$i:
        for($p=96^$c&~$k=3          // init $k to 3, init cursor to value&~3
            ;$k++<8;                // loop 5 times
            $p+=7+($c&3?:-6)            // 2. map [0,1,2,3] to [1,8,9,10], move cursor
        )
            $r[$p]=o;                   // 1. plot
echo chunk_split($r,9);     // insert a linebreak every 9 characters, print
```

**some golfing explained**

- Since `^96` has no effect on the lower two bits, it can be ignored when extracting the direction; so there is no need to store the value in a variable, which saves 5 bytes on the cursor init.
- Using `~3` instead of `124` saves one byte and allows the next golfing:
- Initializing the looping counter `$k=3` inside the `$p` assignment saves two bytes
  and it doesn´t hurt the pre-condition (since the upper value still has one digit).
- Using a string for the result has the shortest initialization and plotting possible: When a character is set beyond the end of a string, PHP implicitly sets the missing characters to space. And `chunk_split` is the shortest way to insert the linebreaks.
  I don´t even want to know how much more anything else would take.
- `7+($c&3?:-6)` is one byte shorter than `$c&3?$c%4+7:1`.
- Added `hexdec()` (8 bytes) to satisfy the input restriction.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, <s>184</s> <s>183</s> <s>178</s> <s>168</s> 167 bytes

```js
f=
n=>[...`<>K[LM]NO\\^k{lm}no|~`].map((e,i)=>n>>i&1&&[0,2,4,6,8].map(i=>a[(e&102)*4+(e&17||15)*i]=`o`,e=~e.charCodeAt()),a=[...(` `.repeat(31)+`
`).repeat(9)])&&a.join``
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(+this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Was originally 206 bytes but @Arnauld's answer inspired me to investigate a one-dimensional array solution. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @edc65. Saved <s>5</s> 15 bytes thanks to @Arnauld. Saved a further byte by tweaking the choice of characters.

Comment: `[0,1,2,3,4]` is shorter

Comment: I think you can save 4 bytes by using `[67,65,52,36,51,50,34,49,48,35,33,20,4,19,18,2,17,16,3,1]` and `[0,2,4,6,8].map(i=>a[(e&102)*4+(e&17||15)*i]='o')`

Comment: Or you can use `[..."ecVFUTDSREC6&54$32%#"]` and `[0,2,4,6,8].map(i=>a[(e&102)*4+(e&17||15)*i]='o',e=e.charCodeAt()-34)` to save 10 more bytes.

Comment: @Arnauld You seem to have undercounted your saving by 1, and I also managed to golf off an extra byte by using `~` instead of `-34` (sadly I fall foul of `\\` which is why I don't save 2 bytes).

Comment: I wonder if you could replace this '\' with ASCII character #220.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 491 bytes

```
@set n=%1
@for %%i in ("720896 524288 524288 524288 843776 262144 262144 262144 268288" "131072 65536 0 32768 16384 8192 0 4096 2048" "131072 0 98304 0 16384 0 12288 0 2048" "131072 32768 0 65536 16384 4096 0 8192 2048" "165248 1024 1024 1024 89312 512 512 512 10764" "256 128 0 64 32 16 0 8 4" "256 0 192 0 32 0 24 0 4" "256 64 0 128 32 8 0 16 4" "322 2 2 2 171 1 1 1 17")do @set s=&(for %%j in (%%~i)do @set/am=%1^&%%j&call:c)&call echo(%%s%%
:c
@if %m%==0 (set s=%s%  )else set s=%s%o
```

Note: The last line ends with a space. Putting an `if` conditional with a variable inside a `for` loop is beyond batch so that needs its own subroutine. Since it does nothing visible I fall through into it to exit. The `~` unquotes the strings in the outer loop allowing the inner loop to loop over the numbers. The numbers are simply the bitmasks for all the places where `o`s should be drawn.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <strike>267</strike> <strike>262</strike> <strike>260</strike> 256 characters

Counting escapes as 1 character

```
void f(int i){char*k="\0\x1\x2\x3\x4\x4\x5\x6\x7\x8\0\x9\x12\x1b\x24\0\xa\x14\x1e\x28\x4\xc\x14\x1c\x2d\x4\xd\x16\x1f\x28\x4\xe\x18\x22\x2c\x8\x10\x18\x20\x28\x8\x11\x1a\x23\x2c\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x24\x2d\x36\x3f\x48\x24\x2e\x38\x42\x4c\x28\x30\x38\x40\x48\x28\x31\x3a\x43\x4c\x28\x31\x3a\x43\x4c\x28\x32\x3c\x46\x50\x2c\x35\x3e\x47\x50\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4c\x4d\x4e\x4f\x50";for(int n=0,s,l;n<81;!(++n%9)&&putchar(10))for(s=l=0;s<20;!(++l%5||++s^20)&&putchar(32))if(i<<s&1<<19&&k[l]==n&&putchar(111))break;}
```

k is a lookup referring to which boxes to put an 'o' in.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#bZLhbpswFIX/5yncSkW4VIt9bUMQ8Kdp8hJlkwgBzQpzIqCVpbbPnl4DXT1pUpxwjj@fc4WzXhOuYkJIWJ@PDV2t1xGwe4X6RLTRo646PVSjPpsfhJP6d9VX9dj05IKrGerqMp0pQMXX17M@kjbUZiSavjn0/lTclqy0vLRQWlFaOX1UaePSJqXduM0U93GXHxCSzqhQIMUbNDbTgXpx8BeOk4PfHDN4@5dBmuMTYBTULtpytlhshpyFk3DMBzFTWGgBxwHMgmTGpoVDgeMOHoedAjmBnXKzeNgqXD@2yno@K9jisYVzHvYKzJPC4/7nudeEzxJ7FJu7Bc4nsEcms@cyJc4n3dnDfHZa7s04rnXcbdae@@kuTMEehocuM/mGZzdhFJm7lAbB5WV0VxRyRqlDh6IrWDbkwCaou1Pv71E0/ALmwQIo1XjFeT4EPM95GgSn5@5nURgvkHNKD31TnbKPqxvgT6VNSMnbCv9lbcjsjm1B0exLbjmT4lvu5B6Sb7nnqfLkE9vGnkzVTjBfxgBespKxn6zSxOt9VDtf7uX2H6mevmTfjC@9ISxbfVw/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge, 468 bytes

```
~:85+`!#v_86*-:9`7*-48*%\82**+
3%2:/2\<$v0%2:/2\*g02*!g03%2:/2\*!+4g07%2:/2\*g02*!-8g06%2:/2\*g02*!-4g0
g!*20g*^00>50g*\2/:2%00g8-!*40g*\2/:2%30g8-!*20g*\2/:2%60g66+-!*\2/:2%70
`\5:p00:<g^*!-8g00%2:\-10:\p07-g00:p06+g00:p05`3:p04`\5:p03:<0\p02`3:p01
#o 8`#@_^4>*50g*\2/2%00g!*40g*0\>:#<1#\+_$!1+4g,48*,\1+:8`!#^_55+,$\1+:
g03%2:/2<-^!g00%2:/2\*g01*!g03%2:/2\*g01*!g07%2:/2\*!-4g06%2:/2\*g01*!-4
70g4-!*\^>!*50g*\2/:2%00g4-!*40g*\2/:2%30g8-!*10g*\2/:2%60g8-!*10g*\2/:2%
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=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&input=RTBDMjU)

The first line reads a string from stdin, evaluating it as a hexadecimal number. The rest of the code is essentially just a double loop over the x/y coordinates of the grid, with a massive boolean calculation determining whether an `o` should be output for each location.

There's basically a separate condition for each of the 20 grid points, for example (the first four):

```
(y==0) * (x<5) * bit0
(y==0) * (x>3) * bit1
(x==0) * (y<5) * bit2
(x==y) * (y<5) * bit3
```

And then once we've calculated all 20 of them, we OR the lot together, and if that result is true, we output a `o`, otherwise we output a space.

Befunge doesn't have anything in the way of bit manipulation operations, so to extract the bits from the input, we're just repeatedly evalating `n%2` and then `n/=2` as we make our way through the 20 condition calculations.